# Android cannot get webview to display utube videos and google maps

Tags: android, webview

If I use WebView to display a page having a utube video or google map, I only get a big grey box, it workcs fine if I call up the  web browser.

Is there some way a WebView can show this content?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to enable javascript: [`setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptEnabled%28boolean%29)

Update: edited as per @Matthew Willis' comment.

Comment: wouldn't this allow the WebView to control Java features via Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You may need [webview.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptEnabled%28boolean%29).